# Cannot create a UdpClient on IPv6

Tags: c#, ipv6, udpclient

What I thought would be a simple task, has turned into a bit of a nightmare.

What it boils down to now, is I need to create a UDP listener on port 8888, on a specific link local IPv6 address.

I get an exception thrown when the following line is executed:

```
_udpSoc = new UdpClient(MONITOR_INPUT_EVENT_SOCKET, AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
```

(where MONITOR_INPUT_EVENT_SOCKET is a const int of value 8888)

Having tried to look for support, I even find [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/264kf1ye.aspx) describing exactly the same line.

The SocketException thrown is "The requested address is not valid in its context" with an ErrorCode of 10049 with a stacktrace of:

```
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(Int32 port, AddressFamily family)
at [my code...]
```

Alternatively, if I change the problem line to:

```
_udpSoc = new UdpClient(_groupEp);
```

(where _groupEp is an IPEndPoint set to IPAddress.Any, with the ScopeId set the the correct interface, and port of MONITOR_INPUT_EVENT_SOCKET)

...and get an exception of "The requested address is not valid in its context", with the same ErrorCode and stack trace as before.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Just to add, if I remove the ScopeId (set to 0, default value), the UdpClient is created but does not receive the data (which can be seen on wireshark)

Comment: `Socket.OSSupportsIPv6` is true? (this value reflects some .net configuration as well)

Comment: 10049 really suggests you don't have IPv6 on your computer.  Using `UdpClient(IPEndPoint)` as you described sounds like it's using IPv4

Comment: I definitely have IPv6 support - I have an active telnet session over IPv6 (link local) to the target in the same application.

Comment: I would still check it as OSSupportsIPv6 also reflects whether IPV6 is enabled in the current .net system.net config

Comment: `Socket.OSSupportsIPv6` returns true although interestingly the deprecated `Socket.SupportsIPv6` returns false.

Comment: This won't work on Windows XP. Make sure you have Vista SP2 or later.